# Error Running Wildfly Image java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: docker, wildfly

I'm trying to run a Wildfly image using Wildfly 27 and Java 17, but I'm getting this error message during the image execution.

```
15:24:20,779 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 82) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."XXX.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."XXX.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.KeycloakServletExtension does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void handleDeployment(io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo, jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)' of interface io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension.
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.KeycloakServletExtension does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void handleDeployment(io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo, jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)' of interface io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension.
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.handleExtensions(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:282)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:156)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@27.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
        ... 8 more

15:24:20,785 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "XXX.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"XXX.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.KeycloakServletExtension does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void handleDeployment(io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo, jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)' of interface io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension.
    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.KeycloakServletExtension does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void handleDeployment(io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo, jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)' of interface io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension."}}
```

I'm using these dependencies in my pom.xml incase it helps

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- next is under surveillance ;) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-osgi-thirdparty</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0.CR1</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Is your keycloak installation JakartaEE 10 ?

Comment: how can I find this one out? I'm kinda new to Eclipse and using already deployed stuff

Comment: What is Keycloak version 1.7.0.CR1 seems quite old (2015) so it won't run on JakartaEE 10

Comment: You no longer need the Keycloak client adapters with Wildfly - that stopped in Wildfly 24.

Comment: but if I remove the keycloak adapter, then I can't mvn install/deploy my project